# Javascript:How to remove occurrence of a character from a value?

Tags: javascript, regex

Here i am trying to replace an occurrence of a string and 4 characters after that by blank.

For Eg i have the below string:

```
var a=ssss~ABC*bvbfg~JJJ*ertert~PMU*trert~GFRG*qqqq~HGHGHG
```

I get the value as `bvbfg`

Now when i get the value i should replace `bvbfg~JJJ` to blank value and the string should become

```
var a=ssss~ABC*ertert~PMU*trert~GFRG*qqqq~hghgh
```

Similarly if i get the value as `qqqq` i should replace `qqqq~HGHGHG` to blank value

and the new value should be

```
var a=ssss~ABC*bvbfg~JJJ*ertert~PMU*trert~GFRG
```

I tried making using of regular expression:

Something as below(For Eg)

```
mystring.replace(/bvbfg/g , "newchar");
```

But the results i saw were not good. It is a bit tricky. Any guidance. Thanks.

Comment: Try [`replace(/bvbfg~[^*]*\*?/g, '')`](https://regex101.com/r/eqbibe/2)

Comment: I read your question twice but I still did not understand

Comment: do you want to replace for both cases at one time?

Comment: How did `HGHGHG` become `hghgh` ?

Comment: I want to do what solution has been given by @ Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew . It was quick and awesome

Comment: If you only have ASCII letters/digits/`_` after `~` the answer below will also work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  How do i pass bvbfg to regex?

Comment: You got an answer below from ibrahim. But it is a good idea to escape the `tok`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function remove(str, tok) {
  var regex = new RegExp('\\b' + tok + '~[^*]*\\*?', 'i'); // if you want it to be case sensetive, then remove the 'i' parameter
  return str.replace(regex, '')
          /*.replace(/^\*|\*$/, '')*/; // uncomment this to remove *s from the start and the end
}

var a = "ssss~ABC*bvbfg~JJJ*ertert~PMU*trert~GFRG*qqqq~HGHGHG";

console.log(remove(a, "ertert"));
```

**Parse:**

```js
function parse(str) {
  return str.split('*')
            .reduce(function(res, e) {
              var parts = e.split('~');
              res[parts[0]] = parts[1];
              return res;
            }, {});
}

var a = "ssss~ABC*bvbfg~JJJ*ertert~PMU*trert~GFRG*qqqq~HGHGHG";

console.log(parse(a));
```

Comment: Thanks mate +1: in case of abc,ertert,werer,asdasd. If i want to remove ertert . is there any regex that can help me to get abc,werer,asdasd. I will accept your answer

Comment: If `tok` starts with a non-word char, `\b` will make it fail. I hope it is not the case here.

Comment: @NitheshKumar You mean like parse it into an object (key-value pairs)?

Answer (score 0):

I am new to regex, this is what I tried and it seems to work.
`/bvbfg~(\w+)[*]?/g`

Demo: http://regexr.com/3fagf

But I would suggest you to use  Wiktor Stribiżew's answer.

Comment: How do i pass bvbfg to regex?

Comment: You need to make a function for that, check ibrahim mahrir's answer

Answer (score 0):

Here you go... short and simple :)

```js
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
var value = document.getElementById('value').value,
    a = 'ssss~ABC*bvbfg~JJJ*ertert~PMU*trert~GFRG*qqqq~HGHGHG',
    regx = new RegExp('\\*?' + value + '~\\w*', 'g');
console.log(a.replace(regx, ''));
}
```

```html
<input id="value" type="text">
<button id="btn">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting everything together with Stribiżew's regex:

```js
function getRegexp(s) {
  return new RegExp( s + '~[^*]*\\*?', 'gi');
}

var str = 'ssss~ABC*bvbfg~JJJ*ertert~PMU*trert~GFRG*qqqq~HGHGHG';

var s = 'bvbfg';
console.log(str.replace(getRegexp(s), ''));

s = 'qqqq';
console.log(str.replace(getRegexp(s), ''));
```